# CentOS7 hostnamectl set-hostname messes up with /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: centos, networking

CentOS7. Network is all OK.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Then I decide to change the host name.

```
# hostnamectl set-hostname host.domain
# reboot
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
search domain


# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your
# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:
#
# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com
```

Why does `hostnamectl set-hostname` mess up my `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: i think it is not becuse of set-hostname , it is because of reboot and then dhclient runs to populate the resolv.conf , you should tell the system not to update resolv.conf , so that you can make it kind of static by setting peer dns= no

Comment: That should be `PEERDNS=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<inf>`.  It's not necessarily dhcpclient, but may be NetworkManager.  If you specify `DNS1`, `DNS2`, and `DOMAIN` in the same file, it should create the correct `/etc/resolv/conf` for you.

Comment: I added PEERDNS=no in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<inf>. Rebooted. Didn't work. Same result.

Comment: If you don't have `DNS1`, `DNS2`, and `DOMAIN` in this file, you need to manually add the correct lines to your `/etc/resolv.conf` (i.e. `search` and `nameserver`).

Answer (score 2):

Just to reiterate, as an official answer, what MikeA says in the question's comments:

> It's not necessarily dhcpclient, but may be NetworkManager. If you
>   specify DNS1, DNS2, and DOMAIN in the same file, it should create the
>   correct /etc/resolv/conf for you.
>
> If you don't have DNS1, DNS2, and
>   DOMAIN in this file, you need to manually add the correct lines to
>   your /etc/resolv.conf (i.e. search and nameserver) - MikeA

I followed his comments and was successful (see further down for more detail).

**NetworkManager (CentOS 7 - current way)**

1. Add following lines to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<inf>`:

   `DNS1=8.8.8.8
   DNS2=8.8.4.4
   DOMAIN=mydomain.com`
2. Reboot

**"static" resolv.conf (the old way)**

1. `PEERDNS=no` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<inf>`
2. Manually add correct lines to `/etc/resolv.conf` (i.e. search, nameserver)
   (This is essentially how

**More Information & Details**

---

I came to this question as result of a network error.

Server is a CentOS 7 virtual machine running in KVM environment.

OS was installed via SolusVM Control Panel template.

After installing CentOS 7, I did one of two ways to change the hostname, but I can't remember which:

- `hostname myserver.mydomain.com`; or
- Used SolusVM Control Pannel's Hostname tab

I'm fairly certain, I only did the latter, as I have an init GIT commit that shows `hostname` and `resolv.conf` using the old hostname, but `hosts` has a single entry with static IP and new hostname/domain. See below for diffs.

It seems this change did not persist for one reason or another, when the VM was suspended via SolusVM (or KVM manager), resulting in reboot, the hostname was reverted back to the original by `systemd`.

I then discovered that in CentOS 7 the hostname should be set using `hostnamectl set-hostname myserver.mydomain.com`. [1]

After doing this and rebooting, I found I had no DNS resolution, e.g. `nslookup google.com` and `ping google.com` resulted in DNS / no resolution errors.

It seems like whatever DNS configuration that may have been set via the SolusVM CentOS 7 install template was wiped out by the NetworkManager, although I can't say for certain who / what caused the changes, but it's definitely clear from GIT that changes were made to `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/machine-info` right after running `hostnamectl ...` command (again, see below for diffs).

Here are the exact steps I did for anyone one in a similar situation, for troubleshooting, or as an explicit example:

**Objective: Update hostname.domainname (fqdn)**

(explicitly: myOLDhostname.myOLDdomain.com -> myNEWhostname.myNEWdomain.com)

1. Initial state:

   - `hostname`: `myOLDhostname.myOLDdomain.com`
   - `resolv.conf`:
     `# Generated by NetworkManager
     search myOLDdomain.com
     nameserver 8.8.8.8
     nameserver 8.8.4.4`
   - `machine-info`: `/dev/null` (i.e. not existing)
2. Ran command `hostnamectl set-hostname myNEWhostname.myNEWdomain`
3. Reboot. After restart, I re-ssh back into VM.
4. Try `nslookup google.com`, `ping google.com`, get errors like: `ping: unknown host google.com`
5. `cat /etc/resolv.conf` now shows:
   `# Generated by NetworkManager`
   `search myNEWdomain.com`


   `# No nameservers found; try putting DNS servers into your`
   `# ifcfg files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts like so:`
   `# DNS1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
   `# DNS2=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`
   `# DOMAIN=lab.foo.com bar.foo.com`
6. After searching, I find `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` has no `DNS1`, `DNS1`, and `DOMAIN` entries, this causes missing `nameserver` entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
7. I append the following via `sudoedit /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:
   `DNS1=8.8.8.8`
   `DNS2=8.8.4.4`
   `DOMAIN=myNEWdomain.com`
8. I again run command `hostnamectl set-hostname myNEWhostname.myNEWdomain`
9. However, I still have no DNS, `nslookup` and `ping` still fail.
10. I try to restart NetworkManager as recommended `systemctl restart NetworkManager.service`
11. Still no DNS, so I run command `reboot`
12. After reboot, I login via ssh again and IT WORKS. `ping` and `nslookp` are both successful.
13. Now, I check `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and see included `nameserver` entries:

    `# Generated by NetworkManager`
    `search myNEWdomain.com`
    `nameserver 8.8.4.4`
    `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

For GIT, I use `etckeeper` (essentially manages a GIT repository in `/etc`) and it shows the initial configuration, and that explicitly, there had been no other changes to the network related files of `/etc/{hostname,resolv.conf,hosts}` until running the `hostnamectl` command.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. Can't believe that the configuration of my VPS (SolusVM, CentOS 7) is exactly the same as OP and it similarly ran into the DNS issue after I set a new hostname.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell Networkmanager not to change `resolv.conf` by adding a `nodns` snippet in the main section in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/nodns.conf`:

```
[main]
dns=none
```

(don't forget `systemctl restart NetworkManager`)